# Setting up a bukkit server for personal use on linux, isn't installing properly, not sure why

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bukkit, linux, minecraft-java-edition-server

I have been trying to set up a bukkit server to run on localhost, so that I'd be the only one playing it.

I had someone on another forum help me get started by saying, basically, "Download the latest bukkit.jar from [here](http://dl.bukkit.org/downloads/craftbukkit/list/dev/), make folder and put that in it with a start.sh file that launches it ([like this](https://gist.github.com/riddle/6111533)) and it will self populate the folder you put it in." The only difference in the start.sh I made was I listed the full path to the directory, and shrank the ram size to 1G. That didn't work, it wasn't populating the directory at all. So I tried loading the vanilla minecraft_server.jar, didn't work either.

I was told it could be a permission problem but it all looks fine to me. Below you can see the path to the craftbukkit.jar, aswell as the permissions from there. I'd appreciate any help, as I am very very new to any type of server setup.

```
ra@ra-desktop:~$ ls -al ~/.minecraft | grep Bukkit && ls -al ~/.minecraft/Bukkit 
drwxr-xr-x  2 ra ra    4096 2013-07-31 22:00 Bukkit
total 20896
drwxr-xr-x  2 ra ra     4096 2013-07-31 22:00 .
drwxr-xr-x 23 ra ra     4096 2013-07-31 00:54 ..
-rwxr-xr-x  1 ra ra 15249389 2013-07-30 08:54 craftbukkit-1.6.2.jar
-rwxr--r--  1 ra ra  6134331 2013-07-31 22:00 minecraft_server.1.6.2.jar
-rwxr-xr-x  1 ra ra       91 2013-07-31 22:00 start.sh
```

My `start.sh` looks like this now:

```
#!/bin/sh
 BINDIR=$(dirname "$(readlink -fn "$0")")
 cd "$BINDIR"
 java -Xmx1024M -jar craftbukkit-1.6.2.jar -o true
```

Here's the output though, being run from `/home/ra/.minecraft/Bukkit`:

```
ra@ra-desktop:~/.minecraft/Bukkit$ bash start.sh
start.sh: line 2: /home/ra/.minecraft/Bukkit: is a directory
03:43:47 [INFO] Starting minecraft server version 1.6.2
03:43:47 [INFO] Loading properties
03:43:47 [INFO] Default game type: SURVIVAL
03:43:47 [INFO] Generating keypair
03:43:47 [INFO] Starting Minecraft server on *:25565
03:43:47 [INFO] This server is running CraftBukkit version git-Bukkit-1.5.2-R1.0-35-g4176258-b2823jnks (MC: 1.6.2) (Implementing API version 1.6.2-R0.1-SNAPSHOT)
03:43:47 [INFO] Preparing level "FunInTheHELL"
03:43:48 [INFO] Preparing start region for level 0 (Seed: 8440585574752452648)
03:43:49 [INFO] Preparing spawn area: 9%
03:43:50 [INFO] Preparing spawn area: 22%
03:43:50 [INFO] ----- Bukkit Auto Updater -----
03:43:50 [INFO] It appears that you're running a Development Build, when you've specified in bukkit.yml that you prefer to run Recommended Builds.
03:43:50 [INFO] If you would like to be kept informed about new Development Build releases, it is recommended that you change 'preferred-channel' in your bukkit.yml to 'dev'.
03:43:50 [INFO] With that set, you will be told whenever a new version is available for download, so that you can always keep up to date and secure with the latest fixes.
03:43:50 [INFO] If you would like to disable this warning, simply set 'suggest-channels' to false in bukkit.yml.
03:43:50 [INFO] ----- ------------------- -----
03:43:51 [INFO] Preparing spawn area: 37%
03:43:52 [INFO] Preparing spawn area: 47%
03:43:53 [INFO] Preparing spawn area: 59%
03:43:54 [INFO] Preparing spawn area: 74%
03:43:55 [INFO] Preparing spawn area: 93%
03:43:56 [INFO] Preparing start region for level 1 (Seed: 8440585574752452648)
03:43:57 [INFO] Preparing spawn area: 16%
03:43:58 [INFO] Preparing spawn area: 28%
03:43:59 [INFO] Preparing spawn area: 48%
03:44:00 [INFO] Preparing spawn area: 69%
03:44:01 [INFO] Preparing spawn area: 90%
03:44:01 [INFO] Preparing start region for level 2 (Seed: 8440585574752452648)
03:44:02 [INFO] Preparing spawn area: 50%
03:44:03 [INFO] Server permissions file permissions.yml is empty, ignoring it
03:44:03 [INFO] Done (15.852s)! For help, type "help" or "?"
>stop
03:44:39 [INFO] CONSOLE: Stopping the server..
03:44:39 [INFO] Stopping server
03:44:39 [INFO] Saving players
03:44:39 [WARNING] DSCT: Socket closed
03:44:39 [INFO] Saving worlds
03:44:39 [INFO] Closing listening thread
03:44:39 [INFO] Saving chunks for level 'FunInTheHELL'/Overworld
03:44:40 [INFO] Saving chunks for level 'FunInTheHELL_nether'/Nether
03:44:40 [INFO] Saving chunks for level 'FunInTheHELL_the_end'/The End
```

… and here's the output run from any other directory:

```
ra@ra-desktop:~/[literally-anywhere]$ bash ~/.minecraft/Bukkit/start.sh
/home/ra/.minecraft/Bukkit/start.sh: line 2: /home/ra/.minecraft/Bukkit: is a directory
03:51:44 [INFO] Starting minecraft server version 1.6.2
03:51:44 [INFO] Loading properties
03:51:44 [WARNING] server.properties does not exist
03:51:44 [INFO] Generating new properties file
03:51:44 [INFO] Default game type: SURVIVAL
03:51:44 [INFO] Generating keypair
03:51:44 [INFO] Starting Minecraft server on *:25565
03:51:45 [INFO] This server is running CraftBukkit version git-Bukkit-1.5.2-R1.0-35-g4176258-b2823jnks (MC: 1.6.2) (Implementing API version 1.6.2-R0.1-SNAPSHOT)
03:51:45 [WARNING] Failed to load operators list: java.io.FileNotFoundException: ./ops.txt (No such file or directory)
03:51:45 [WARNING] Failed to load white-list: java.io.FileNotFoundException: ./white-list.txt (No such file or directory)
03:51:45 [INFO] Preparing level "world"
03:51:45 [INFO] Preparing start region for level 0 (Seed: 103591942867456033)
03:51:45 [INFO] ----- Bukkit Auto Updater -----
03:51:45 [INFO] It appears that you're running a Development Build, when you've specified in bukkit.yml that you prefer to run Recommended Builds.
03:51:45 [INFO] If you would like to be kept informed about new Development Build releases, it is recommended that you change 'preferred-channel' in your bukkit.yml to 'dev'.
03:51:45 [INFO] With that set, you will be told whenever a new version is available for download, so that you can always keep up to date and secure with the latest fixes.
03:51:45 [INFO] If you would like to disable this warning, simply set 'suggest-channels' to false in bukkit.yml.
03:51:45 [INFO] ----- ------------------- -----
03:51:46 [INFO] Preparing spawn area: 8%
03:51:47 [INFO] Preparing spawn area: 22%
03:51:48 [INFO] Preparing spawn area: 34%
03:51:49 [INFO] Preparing spawn area: 45%
03:51:50 [INFO] Preparing spawn area: 56%
03:51:51 [INFO] Preparing spawn area: 65%
03:51:52 [INFO] Preparing spawn area: 74%
03:51:53 [INFO] Preparing spawn area: 84%
03:51:54 [INFO] Preparing spawn area: 93%
03:51:55 [INFO] Preparing start region for level 1 (Seed: 103591942867456033)
03:51:56 [INFO] Preparing spawn area: 22%
03:51:57 [INFO] Preparing spawn area: 40%
03:51:58 [INFO] Preparing spawn area: 58%
03:51:59 [INFO] Preparing spawn area: 76%
03:52:00 [INFO] Preparing spawn area: 93%
03:52:01 [INFO] Preparing start region for level 2 (Seed: 103591942867456033)
03:52:02 [INFO] Preparing spawn area: 53%
03:52:03 [INFO] Done (17.802s)! For help, type "help" or "?"
```

Shouldn't this keep any population in the Bukkit dir?

Comment: Can you post the output from the command you use to start the servers?  That would give us a better indication of what's going on.

Comment: The command seems to complete properly, but I'm not sure what's happening, because like I said the Bukkit directory is SUPPOSED to be populating, but it's populating my home directory with the bukkit files/subdirectories. [Here's the output though](http://pastebin.com/8deW7VKp), being run from /home/ra/.minecraft/Bukkit and [here's the output run from any other directory](http://pastebin.com/j3PQsKy1)

Also, my start.sh looks like [this](http://pastebin.com/aRXcWSx7) now. Shouldn't this keep any population in the Bukkit dir?

Comment: The first line in the output seems suspicous. Try with a fixed path to `cd` into.

Comment: Oddly the name of the jar file you are executing doesn't exist (according to the output of your `ls` above). I assume this is a typo, and that you aren't somehow executing another jar in a different directory?

Comment: Are you double-clicking this I a graphical interface to run this? That will mess with your working directory.this should be run in the terminal within the Bukkit directory.

Comment: Bryan - that was a typo, the start.sh is using craftbukkit-1.6.2.jar

SevenSidedDie - I am not accessing this via gui.

Maerlyn - I tried that. It returned "cd: 2: can't cd to ~/.minecraft/Bukkit/"

Comment: I've put the info buried in these comments into the actual question.

Comment: Could you run exactly `ls -ld ~/.minecraft/Bukkit` and paste the results into the end of the question? The permissions on the containing folder may not be set correctly.

Answer (score 1):

According to the log output it at least tries to generate the files just fine. Could it be that it is creating the files in a different location? Try this to find out:

```
    cd /
    find . -name "*FunInTheHELL*" -print
```

Depending on the size of your HDD, it might take a while for the command to finish.

Comment: Wouldn't `find ~/ -name "*FunInTheHELL*" -print` make more sense? It's not going to have permission to write anywhere else.

Comment: It isn't generating them anywhere, it's just generating the default (world 1, etc) in my home directory.

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in your `BINDIR` expression: you're using `readlink` incorrectly. From the `man` page for `readlink`:

> If the given argument is not a symbolic link, readlink will
>        print nothing and exit with an error.

So what you're feeding to `dirname` is an empty string, resulting in `BINDIR` being set to the empty string, which makes `cd` change to your home directory. You can confirm this by commenting out the `java` line and adding a line reading `pwd` just before it.

Change it to:

```
#!/bin/sh
 BINDIR=$(dirname "$0")
 cd "$BINDIR"
 pwd
 java -Xmx1024M -jar craftbukkit-1.6.2.jar -o true
```

… and it should work. Lesson: don't uncomment the "execution" line of a script until you've confirmed your `cd`s are working correctly!